# Can't install Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, failed-installation

MSDN AA MSVS 2010 installation throws an exception (app crash). I'm currently using VS 2010 Express Edition. I tried only mounting the iso image and then run setup on the virtual disk. How can I fix this? I need it only for educational purpose.

Comment: I'd recommend emailing Microsoft support or asking on the MSDN forums instead of posting here.

Comment: Thank you! I'll consider that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good link for these kind of errors: [Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 RC and Visual Studio 2010 RC Available Now - Support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2010/02/10/microsoft-net-framework-4-0-rc-and-visual-studio-2010-rc-available-now.aspx)

I quote:

> If you are having problems installing
>   .NET 4.0 or Visual Studio 2010, please
>   visit support forums.
>
> - [.NET Framework Setup](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/threads)
> - [Visual Studio Setup and Installation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/threads)
>
> You may find solutions to common
>   problems right away, or the community
>   – including Microsoft employees – will
>   be glad to assist you. If you are
>   having installation problems, please
>   [download](http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=8967043) and run the [log
>   collection utility](http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=8967044). This creates a
>   vslogs.cab file in your %TEMP%
>   directory that you can upload and
>   paste the link in any correspondence.